# React : Issue with image size before image loaded

Tags: reactjs, lazy-loading, placeholder, image-size

I am displaying images whose sources comes from URLs. These images have different sizes. These images are in `div` which are responsive and for the images to fit as well as possible, they have a width of 100%. So far, so good.

The problem is when loading the image, as it comes from a URL, it can take a little while, before loading it occupies 0x0 pixels and therefore my `div` is not visible, which to causes me display problems until the image is loaded. (You see what I mean?)

In fact what would be the best is to have a placeholder with the same size of the image that will be loaded. Or I wonder if it will be better to get the size of the image and then build the `div`? (but how to do that into the render?) Or, should I use a lazy load component? (For the moment, I haven't found one that manages to take the size of my image before loading it).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work: [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63896591/how-to-render-default-image-before-rendering-the-actual-image-in-react-js)

```
export default function App() {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  function onLoad() {
    // delay for demo only
    setTimeout(() => setIsLoading(false), 1000);

   // setIsLoading(false)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <img
        alt="ad-img"
        width={300}
        src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200/FF0000"
        style={{ display: isLoading ? "block" : "none" }}
      />
      <img
        alt="ad-img"
        width={300}
        src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcS1hIjBaj0A0XNB_xAozRAcFs6Gr0DQhWTGiQ&usqp=CAU"
        style={{ display: isLoading ? "none" : "block" }}
        onLoad={onLoad}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

...we're displaying 2 images, the placeholder and the actual image. While the actual image is loading, we're going to display the placeholder, when its loaded we're going to hide the placeholder and show the actual image.

Comment: Hi Joaquin, Thank you for your fast reply. But the problem is that I don't know the dimensions of the images and images haven't the same size. Placeholder need to be with the same size.